# How do I set an icon to a view in red program?

Tags: icons, red

I want to set an icon for the program main window. I found this page https://www.red-lang.org/2016/03/060-red-gui-system.html which says:

> Icons and other "resources" are now supported for inclusion in Windows executables. They can be set from Red's main script header, these are the currently supported options:

> Icon: file! or block! of files

> If no Icon option is specified, a default Red icon will be provided.

I don't get if I need to do it in the program declaration or elsewhere

```
Red [
    needs view
    icon %icon1.ico
]
; this doesn't seem to work but it also doesn't break the program
```

I have also tried putting the `icon` line in the block defining the view but it is breaking the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right syntax is:

```
Red [
    needs: view
    icon: %icon1.ico
]
```

Also the program needs to be compiled (e.g. `red -c -t windows program.red`). If the program is launched as a script (`do %program.red` in red console app) the icon will not be picked up.